# Array IndexOutOfRange

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
        string temp = textBox1.Text;
        char[] array1 = temp.ToCharArray();
        string temp2 = "" + array1[0];
        string temp3 = "" + array1[1];
        string temp4 = "" + array1[2];
        textBox2.Text = temp2;
        textBox3.Text = temp3;
        textBox4.Text = temp4;
```

How do I prevent an IndexOutOfRange Error occurring when a user inputs less than three letters in textBox1?

Comment: You should check out temp's length (`temp.Length`) and see it it's above three, otherwise show an error or do nothing.

Comment: Can we assume `textBox3.Text = temp4;` this "3" is a typo and not an error and should be "4"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How i will prevent IndexOutOfRange Error if a user only input less than three letters in the textBox1?

Just check that using `temp.Length`:

```
if (temp.Length > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

... or use `switch`/`case`.

Also, you don't need the array at all. Just call `ToString` on each character, or use `Substring`:

```
string temp = textBox1.Text;
switch (temp.Length)
{
    case 0:
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        break;
    case 1:
        // Via the indexer...
        textBox2.Text = temp[0].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        break;
    case 2:
        // Via Substring
        textBox2.Text = temp.Substring(0, 1);
        textBox3.Text = temp.Substring(1, 1);
        textBox4.Text = "";
        break;
    default:
        textBox2.Text = temp.Substring(0, 1);
        textBox3.Text = temp.Substring(1, 1);
        textBox4.Text = temp.Substring(2, 1);
        break;
}
```

Another option - even neater - is to use the conditional operator:

```
string temp = textBox1.Text;
textBox2.Text = temp.Length < 1 ? "" : temp.Substring(0, 1);
textBox3.Text = temp.Length < 2 ? "" : temp.Substring(1, 1);
textBox4.Text = temp.Length < 3 ? "" : temp.Substring(2, 1);
```

Comment: @doctorlove: No, because I'm assuming that as many characters as possible should be filled - see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using `ElementAtOrDefault`:

```
    string[] temp = textBox1.Text.Select(c => c.ToString());
    string temp2 = "" + temp.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
    string temp3 = "" + temp.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    string temp4 = "" + temp.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
    textBox2.Text = temp2;
    textBox3.Text = temp3;
    textBox3.Text = temp4;
```

Comment: `temp2` will be `"\0"` not `string.Empty` anymore

Comment: That will append a `U+0000` when it's too short - it's not clear that that would be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to this kind of problem is to check the length of the source value (array, string, or vector) before accessing its elements. For example:

```
string  temp = textBox1.Text;

if (temp.Length > 0)
    textBox2.Text = temp.Substring(0, 1);
if (temp.Length > 1)
    textBox3.Text = temp.Substring(1, 1);
if (temp.Length > 2)
    textBox4.Text = temp.Substring(2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

### if the size is fixed i.e no. of character is 3 or length is 3 then it must be like .....

`string temp = textBox1.Text;
        char[] array1 = temp.ToCharArray();
         if(temp.length==3)
               {
                   string temp2 = "" + array1[0];
                   string temp3 = "" + array1[1];
                  string temp4 = "" + array1[2];
                   textBox2.Text = temp2;

                   textBox3.Text = temp3;
                   textBox3.Text = temp4;
               }`
this will be work if u r string length is 3....